# Generic error when saving Bitmap in Xamarin

Tags: f#

```
open System.Drawing
let bitmap = new Bitmap(16,16) 
let path =  __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
bitmap.Save(path+"bitmap.png")
```

I wrote the code above to save a instantiated Bitmap into the project folder. I got a Generic Error when I ran the code. The whole bunch of error messages is as below.

> System.Exception: Generic Error [GDI+ status: GenericError]
>      at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status status) [0x00079] in :0 
>      at System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.String filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo encoder, System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters encoderParams) [0x0003d] in :0 
>      at System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.String filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format) [0x00044] in :0 
>      at System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.String filename) [0x00008] in :0 
>      at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Image:Save (string)
>      at .$FSI_0037.main@ () [0x00006] in <4081182357644f828a64898ac573806b>:0 
>      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>      at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in :0

I debugged the code and figured out the following things.

1. the line of code to create a Bitmap worked fine
2. the path in this situation was "/"
3. the code was fine before the Save() function was called

I just started to learn F# and cannot figure out the problem. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: I solved the problem by set the path to to absolute path of the project folder. I am still not sure why I got "/" for the source directory.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead post an answer and when eligible accept said answer. That will tell others that the question is solved. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, the value of `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` normally does *not* end with `/`, so your code should have specified the file name as `path + "/bitmap.png"`. Or better yet, use `Path.Combine` from the `System.IO` namespace, because it will do the right thing whether your path is `"/"` or `"/home/username/something"`.

Comment: @Bugs Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the value of the "**SOURCE_DIRECTORY**" of the code. 
In most cases, the value of **SOURCE_DIRECTORY** does not contain a '/' at the end of it. So the last line of code can be changed to the code below.

```
bitmap.Save(path+"/bitmap.png")
```

I my case, the value of **SOURCE_DIRECTORY** is a single "/". Although I still haven't figured out why, the problem described can be solved by specifying an existing directory with the filename in the bitmap save function.

Comment: You might want to use Path.Combine(path, "bitmap.png") to get platform neutrality...